# Polynomial Regression didn't give proper hypothesis

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, regression

PFB code, here X is the number of levels of positions (i.e. level 1,level 2 ..) and y is the salary range. Polynomial regression isn't giving best fit line, also how can I figure out for X = 20.
Kindly suggest :)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = [[ 1],[ 2],[ 3],[ 4],[ 5],[ 6],[ 7],[ 8],[ 9],[10]]
y = [45000,50000,60000,80000,110000,150000,200000,300000,500000,1000000]

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X)


linearReg_2 = LinearRegression()
linearReg_2.fit(X_poly,y)

# plot polynomial linear regression
plt.scatter(X,y, color = "red")
plt.plot(X,linearReg_2.predict(X_poly), color = "blue")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try increasing the degree to 3 or 4 for a more proper match.

```
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 3)
```

[image]

```
poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 4)
```

[image]

And for predicting a new value, you need to pass it through the same `poly_reg` object and then use `linearReg_2.predict()`

Something like this:

```
X_new = [[20]]

# Observe that I used transform() and not fit_transform()
X_new_poly = poly_reg.transform(X_new)

y_new = linearReg_2.predict(X_new_poly)
```

Comment: Ok Thanks, Vivek, I just forgot to increase degree :)